# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Does not download updates

Tags: 12.04, upgrade

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Update manager shows I have 89 updates available. When I click on install updates it never completes the download of the updates. I think that it never really starts the download. It just sits there with a circle spinning forever.

Comment: Please **edit your question** and add the output of the command `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Answer (score 1):

Restart your system
At boot screen select repair broken packages and then update packages.
you can get root terminal with network support and do

```
aptitude update
aptitude safe-upgrade
aptitude autoclean
```